# Improving javascript code performance

Tags: javascript, performance

Assume you have a webapp with a 1000000 user logins in an hour.

and the following code get executed on each user login :

```
if (DevMode) {
    // make an Ajax call
} else if (RealMode) {
    // make other Ajax call
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Assuming that the DevMode login occurs only for 5% of the total user logins, is it more efficient to write the code as following:

```
 if (RealMode) {
    // make an Ajax call
} else if (DevMode) {
    // make other Ajax call
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Either way, the amount of time spent by JavaScript in that will be absolutely minuscule and it won't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: Okay, so `DevMode` is only 5%. What's the other 95%? 95% `RealMode` and 0% neither? 5% `RealMode` and 90% neither?

Comment: In average you have like just 7 login connections per minute. Set aside your  optimization case, you have enormous amount of time to handle them in every way you like.

Comment: if we assume I have 1,000,000 in an hour ? does that make a difference ? does avoiding doing multiple checks could improve performance ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `RealMode` is the 95% case (you haven't actually said whether it's `RealMode` or `else`) then: Well, yes, because you avoid doing a check that will be false 95% of the time.

It won't **matter** that it's more efficient, though. Testing a variable for truthiness is really, really, really, really, really fast.